# Split a string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I am trying to split the following into two strings.

```
"SERVER1.DOMAIN.COM Running"
```

For this I use the code.

```
Dim Str As String = "SERVER1.DOMAIN.COM Running"
Dim strarr() As String
strarr = Str.Split(" ")
For Each s As String In strarr
    MsgBox(s)
Next
```

This works fine, and I get two message boxes with `"SERVER1.DOMAIN.COM"` and `"Running"`.

The issue that I am having is that some of my initial strings have more than one space.

```
"SERVER1.DOMAIN.COM        Off"
```

There are about eight spaces in-between ".COM" and "Off".

How can I separate this string in the same way?

Comment: Use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim array As String() = strtemp.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: Instead of `" ".ToCharArray()` you can simply use an array of *character literals*:
`strtemp.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this way:

```
Dim line As String = "SERVER1.DOMAIN.COM Running"
Dim separators() As String = {"Domain:", "Mode:"}
Dim result() As String
result = line.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using Regex class:

```
    Dim str() = {"SERVER1.DOMAIN.COM Running", "mydomainabc.es     not-running"}
    For Each s In str
        Dim regx = New Regex(" +")
        Dim splitString = regx.Split(s)
        Console.WriteLine("Part 1:{0}  |  Part 2:{1}", splitString(0), splitString(1))
    Next
```

And the LINQ way to do it:

```
    Dim str() = {"SERVER1.DOMAIN.COM Running", "mydomainabc.es     not-running"}
    For Each splitString In From s In str Let regx = New Regex(" +") Select regx.Split(s)
        Console.WriteLine("Part 1:{0}  |  Part 2:{1}", splitString(0), splitString(1))
    Next
```