# Converting String to integer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have End Date in my DB table.
On load I want to store it in an Integer variable.
I want to use this month in a loop as an end of the loop.

```
objAcademicSession.Load()
Dim months as integer
months = objAcademicSession.EndDate
```

Now I want to end my loop on months.

Comment: please provide an example of what you have and what you want, otherwise no one will understand what you actually need and what's the problem

Comment: show how you want to use your `month` variable in the loop, show example of string in the `EndDate` property. Please help us to help you, instead of getting answers with `If you have...` or `I assume...`

Answer (score 1):

If your Variable has the Data Type: "Date/DateTime", then you can just use this:

```
months = objAcademicSession.EndDate.month
```

If your Variable has the Data Type: "String", then you can use:

```
months = Convert.toInt32(objAcademicSession.EndDate)
```

And if you need to "split" the String because it contains the full date and you just need the month, look at this:
"[VB.NET - Split String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17060042/4640981)"

You can just "cut" the needed part out. But just if you have a date like this: "2014/4/4 16:30:19". Otherwise use the Code above.

Comment: No i want to use this Variable for my FOR LOOP.
So i need this to be an integer

Comment: .month is a Function that provides you with the month number as an Integer. -- How does your objAcademicSession.EndDate look like? -- What Data Type is it? -- Please provide more Informations! -- And what do you even want to process?

Comment: Check my Question Again
@sonorpearl

Comment: The Problem still remains: What Data Type is your objAcademicSession.EndDate? -- How does your DB Structure look like? -- And @Shafay: .month Should do the job.

Comment: objAcademicSession.EndDate is of type String

Comment: @Shafay And how does it look like. Just do a Debug.Print(objAcademicSession.EndDate) and provide us with the result. Also check my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

> objAcademicSession.EndDate is of type String ... I want to use this month in a loop as an end of the loop.

Assuming `EndDate` is "1" thru "12":

```
objAcademicSession.Load()
Dim months As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(objAcademicSession.EndDate, months) Then
    For i As Integer = 1 To months
        Debug.Print(i)
    Next
End If
```

If you have full dates in `EndDate`, please provide us with examples of what they might look like.