# Catching datetime exception

Tags: vb.net

I get a:

> Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The DateTime represented by the string is not
>   supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

For this part of my code:

```
    Dim iString As String = "15/15/17"
    oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(iString, "dd/MM/yy", Nothing)
```

The thing is, i know 15/15/17 is a wrong date, it does not exist in any calendar but what i'm trying to do here is; i want to catch exception when it happens and set `iString` value to `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yy")`

Comment: To catch an or any exception you can use [Try..Catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement)
Also you could split the string yourself, using `string.split` [Similar Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059971/split-a-string-in-vb-net) and then check each item ie day, month year.

Comment: Use `TryParseExact` instead of `ParseExact` and then there will be no exception.